# Error 1004 regardless - dynamic from first to last

Tags: vba

My code is

```
c=application.match("ID",rows(1),0)
Set n_copy_range=range(cells(1,c),Range(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp))
```

I keep getting error 1004 'range' of object '_Global failed'. Tried to set it as integer/long/range, without any sets, with the Set n_copy_range, without but it keeps failing at rows.count part I guess?

My goal is to look which column is "ID", then get the number of column, and when I got it then it suppose to copy from first to the last cell

I can overcome it by

```
Cells(1, c).Select 
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

However I've read that it is not very efficient solution so I try to omitt that so I would love to get rid of that primary error and keep the first form available for me

Answer (score 1):

You were very close:

```
Sub sdklfhsf()
    Dim c As Long, n_copy_range As Range
    c = Application.Match("ID", Rows(1), 0)
    
    Set n_copy_range = Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp))
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much.
ah tried so many variants but this one was so close..thanks once again, I appreaciate